# A source Code Counter

Tags: python

This is from my project [codecount](http://corylutton.com/codecount.html) I use personally that is very similar to cloc.exe or SLOCCount.  The part that I am questioning is where I am calculating when I am in a comment block and have deep nesting, I basically am replacing the sections with blank.  I would like to deal with fixed format files at some point (RPGLE, CLP, etc) where the comments need to have characters in a specific position.

Any review/comments/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
def scanfile(self, filename):
    """ The heart of the codecounter, Scans a file to identify
    and collect the metrics based on the classification. """
    strblock = None
    endblock = None
    inblock = False
    endcode = False
    sha256 = hashlib.sha256()

    if(filename.size == 0):
        logging.info("Skipping File  : " + filename.name)
        return

    # Identify language
    for l in self.langs:
        if(filename.extension in self.langs[l]["ext"]):
            filename.lang = l
            break

    # Unknown files don't need processed
    if(filename.lang is None):
        logging.info("Skipping File  : " + filename.name)
        return

    # Using the with file opening in order to ensure no GC issues.
    with open(filename.path + "/" + filename.name,
            encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as fp:

        for line in fp:
            sha256.update(line.encode("utf-8"))
            filename.lines += 1
            line = line.strip()
            identified = False

            if(line == ""):
                logging.info(" blak  " + str(filename.lines))
                filename.blanks += 1
                continue

            if(endcode):
                filename.comments += 1
                continue

            # Check to see if it is a block or was an opening block
            # ex1 = "/*  */ if x;"          = Code, not inblock
            # ex2 = "*/ if x; /*"           = Code, inblock
            # ex3 = " if x; /*"             = Code, inblock
            # ex4 = "/*  */ if x; /* */ .." = Code, not inblock
            # ex4 = "*/"                    = Comment, not inblock
            # ex5 = "/* */"                 = Comment, not inblock
            # ex6 = "/*"                    = Comment, inblock
            # Two scenarios,
            # 1 - comments removed, code remains
            # 2 - Comments removed but block is open
            if(not inblock):
                for token in self.langs[filename.lang]["bcomm"]:
                    strblock = token
                    endblock = self.langs[filename.lang]["bcomm"][token]

                    while token in line:
                        # If a block has started then check for an exit
                        if(endblock in line):
                            line = line.replace(
                                    line[line.find(strblock):
                                        line.find(endblock)
                                        + len(endblock)], "", 1)
                        else:
                            line = line.replace(
                                    line[line.find(strblock):], "", 1)
                            inblock = True      # left open
            else:
                # Continue until the block ends... when left open
                if(endblock in line):
                    inblock = False     # End the block
                    line = line.replace(
                            line[:line.find(endblock) + len(endblock)],
                            "").strip()
                else:
                    line = ""

            # From the block but no hidden code made it out the back....
            if(line is ""):
                logging.info(" bloc  " + str(filename.lines) + line)
                filename.comments += 1
                continue

            # Check line comment designators
            for token in self.langs[filename.lang]["comment"]:
                if(line.startswith(token)):
                    logging.info(" line  " + str(filename.lines) + line)
                    filename.comments += 1
                    identified = True
                    break

            if(identified):
                continue

            # If not a blank or comment it must be code
            logging.info(" code  " + str(filename.lines) + line)
            filename.code += 1

            # Check for the ending of code statements
            for end in self.langs[filename.lang]["endcode"]:
                if(line == end):
                    endcode = True

    # Store the hash of this file for comparison to others
    logging.info("Total  "
            + " " + str(filename.blanks)
            + " " + str(filename.comments)
            + " " + str(filename.code))
    filename.sha256 = sha256.digest()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple of points:

In Python there is no need to place parentheses after `if`. For example,

```
if(filename.size == 0):
```

Can be replaced with

```
if filename.size == 0:
```

In fact, the latter is the preferred style.

Also, using `format` is preferred to using `+` to append strings. For example,

```
logging.info("Total  "
        + " " + str(filename.blanks)
        + " " + str(filename.comments)
        + " " + str(filename.code))
```

Can be replaced with:

```
log_message = 'Total  {blanks} {comments} {code}'.format(
    blanks=filename.blanks,
    comments=filename.comments,
    code=filename.code)
logging.info(log_message)
```

This has a few advantages: more readable, easier to internationalize (one single string token instead of multiple), has descriptive named place holders, and finally, will allow for easier formatting if you decide to add it at some point. For example, you can change `{comments}` to `{comments:05d}` to format it as a fixed-width number with width 5 and zeros padded on the left if necessary.

Comment: FWIW, you can also use `'Total {fname.blanks} {fname.comments} {fname.code}'.format(fname=filename)`.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of having to update the number of lines each iteration through the file, you could use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function and only assign the line number once:

```
with open('test_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f):
        # Insert parsing code here
        pass

    # Assign line amount here. A NameError error will be thrown
    # if this code is run on a file with no lines. If this errors,
    # assign 0.
    try:
        filename.lines = line_num + 1
    except NameError:
        filename.lines = 0
```

Also, when creating filepaths, look into using [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). This creates the normalized version of the desired filepath for the current OS:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('some_path', 'to_my', 'file.txt')
'some_path\\to_my\\file.txt'
```

Comment: On the enumerate, I thought about that but thought it would be wrong if the file happens to have no lines.?  I think your right on the os.path.join, I should switch that, got bit by that once before.  Thanks.

Comment: If the code is ran with a file with no lines, line_num will be undefined. I will update accordingly.